# Sum of values from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
col1  col2  value
A   | B   | 2
c   | B   | 4
D   | B   | 1
B   | E   | 3
```

How can I get the sum of values of the rows where there is `B`? In my case, it should be `10`.

I wrote a query to sum values of `B` in `col2`. Here it is:

```
Select col2, sum(value)
from myTable
group by col2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So `B` can be either in `col1` or `col2`?

Comment: If B is in both col1 and col2 for a row, do you expect the value to be added once or twice?

Answer (score 4):

This will sum all values where either `col1` or `col2` is B:

```
Select sum(value)
from myTable
where (col1 = 'B') or (col2 = 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(Tot)
FROM 
(
Select sum(value) Tot
from myTable
WHERE col1 = 'B'
UNION ALL
Select sum(value) Tot
from myTable
WHERE col2 = 'B'
)A